# Publishing a list, and echo its topic duplicate item problem

Tags: python, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I publish to a list by looping through recognized people on camera. Even though 2 people display action 0 and action 1 respectively, topic either says they both display 0 or 1. Do you see what is wrong with it?

My code and topic echo is below:

```
def callback(self, msg):
    human_list_length = len(msg.human_list)
    self.publisher_msg.num_humans = human_list_length
    self.publisher_msg.gesture_list = [GestureDetectorHuman()] * human_list_length
    rospy.loginfo("Visible humans:" + str(human_list_length))
    for human in msg.human_list:
        ind = msg.human_list.index(human)
        rospy.loginfo("Gesture from Human: " + str(ind))
        self.publisher_msg.gesture_list[ind].human_index = ind
        # Check gesture published by current human and publish respective message
        if self.hand_raise(human):
            self.publisher_msg.gesture_list[ind].gesture = str(0)
        elif self.wait_a_minute(human):
            self.publisher_msg.gesture_list[ind].gesture = str(1)
```

rostopic echo output:

```
num_humans: 2 
gesture_list: 
  - 
    human_index: 1
    gesture: "0"
  - 
    human_index: 1
    gesture: "0"
--- 
num_humans: 2 
gesture_list: 
  - 
    human_index: 1
    gesture: "1"
  - 
    human_index: 1
    gesture: "1"
--- 
num_humans: 2 
gesture_list: 
  - 
    human_index: 1
    gesture: "0"
  - 
    human_index: 1
    gesture: "0"
--- 
num_humans: 2 
gesture_list: 
  - 
    human_index: 1
    gesture: "0"
  - 
    human_index: 1
    gesture: "0"
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289504/publishing-a-list,-and-echo-its-topic-duplicate-item-problem/) by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-24**:
I don't understand how the two snippets you posted are related. The second is the Output of `rostopic echo`, I guess. But what about the first? Is this supposed to be the callback reacting to the data in the topic? I don't see a `human_list` field in the Output below. Or should this produce the ...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-24**:
posted message? I'm guessing the second. But there is the question, what do the `hand_raise` and `wait_a_minute` functions do. My guess, your problem is in there.

Maybe describe in more Detail what you expect to happen where, and post the code of the publishers and relevant functions...

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-04-24**:
I can post the full code but its too long. The problem is message published is instead of adding new element inside for loop, it makes all list elements the last added element.
wait_a_minute and hand_raise are the functions called they work just fine as the return is true or false.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-24**:
Whoops, missed that the `human_index` is actually the same to. This is the crucial part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Problem is in how you generate the list of objects to begin with. The `*` multiply will link each copy to the same instance. Thus, you Change both objects with the same call.

You should generate the list by either Clearing it and appending the appropriate newly generated `GestureDetectorHuman` object or use something else for generating the list, as e.g.

```
self.publisher_msg.gesture_list = [ GestureDetectorHuman() for _ in range(human_list_length)]
```

---

**EDIT**

Strange, I just tested this with a simple python class

```
class test(object):
    a = 0
```

and the behaviour is as expected.

```
a = [test()] * 5
```

creates references to the same object (i.e. changing `a[0].a` changes also `a[1].a` etc), whereas

```
b = [ test() for _ in range(5) ]
```

creates 5 objects, and changing works.

You could check by simply `print a` and see to which id the single elements are pointing.

Why this DOES work for simple, immutable types in python, is explained in several places. One that I like (though I'm not the python expert, and am not sure if this is the full true solution) is a comment in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438938/python-copy-through-assignment):

> Everything is an object, and variables
> are names that we assign to objects
> (not the other way around!) So if you
> do a = b = c = 1; a +=1, then
> everything gets assigned to the object
> 1, and then a gets assigned to the
> object 2. With mutable objects like
> lists, dicts and sets, you can change
> the object itself, which will be seen
> by all names assigned to that object,
> but with ints, strings, tuples, and
> other immutable objects, all you can
> do is assign the name to a different
> object.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tolga-uni-lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/34029/tolga-uni-lu/) on 2018-04-24**:
How does my way is different than List = [double] * 5. This just defines the type, buy you can change each element inside the list.
I applied your way it did not work. But mistake must be somewhere there. Thank you for your answer.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-25**:
see edit above